# Nodemailer "connect ETIMEDOUT" with custom domain

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm making a forgot password backend route in Node.js and I'm attempting to use nodemailer to send the email from a custom domain I purchased from namecheap.com, along with the email domain. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the host, the port/security, or the auth. However, when I change the host it gives a a ECONREFUSED error instead so I believe that part is working. My firewall is (as far as I can tell) disabled and I restarted, however it is harder to tell because Norton Antivirus controls it.

This is my code, taken from a router.get route in my back-end.

The full error is "connect ETIMEDOUT" then an ip address with :587 at the end.

```
const transporter = createTransport({
        host: 'axotl.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: config.get('emailUser'),
            pass: config.get('emailPass')
        }
    });
    let resetLink = '';
    let authToken = '';
    await jwt.sign({ email: req.params.email }, config.get('JWTSecret'), { expiresIn: 10800000 }, (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        authToken += token;
    })
    resetLink = await `${config.get('productionLink')}/recipients/resetpassword/${authToken}`
    console.log(`resetlink : ${resetLink}`)
    const mailOptions = {
        from: '"Axotl Support" <support@axotl.com>',
        to: req.params.email,
        subject: "Forgot Password",
        text: `Hello ${req.name},\n\nHere is the password reset link you requested (expires in 3 hours): ${resetLink}\nIf you did not request this, please notify us at http://axotl.com/support\n\nThanks!\n-Axotl Support`
    }
    try {
        console.log('trycatch entered')
            // const verified = await transporter.verify()
            // console.log(`verified : ${verified}`)
        const res = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
        console.log('email completed')
        console.log(res)

        res.json({ msg: "email sent" })
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error")
    }
```

Comment: Can you telnet to axotl.com port 587?

Comment: Telnet can't open a connection even when I disable my firewall through norton. Settings are a little confusing with this, because windows says Norton has control over my firewall but when I disable Norton's firewall it doesn't seem to fully disable the windows defender firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong host domain-- the service doesn't directly host the email domain on the website. I don't know enough about this specific section. I changed it to the email host and it worked.